# Need to find the minimum possible interval where $f(1/3)$ lies

Tags: calculus

Need to find the minimum possible interval where $f(1/3)$ lies

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSjHS.png

I know that $P_2(x)$ is the same. So $f(x)$ is going to be in an interval $(\frac{112}{81} - \frac{1}{3})|x^3| = \frac{85}{81}|x^3|$

is this correct? really not sure what i am doing here.

Comment: You need some more context to your question: what exactly is $P_2 (x)$? Is it the second term of a Taylor series. In addition, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @TobyMak sorry, Yes, P2(x) is the second term of a taylor series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified what is $P_2(x)$, but you can eliminate it from both sides:

$$\frac{1}{3}x^3 < f(x) < \frac{112}{81}x^{3}$$

and now substituting $x = \frac{1}{3}$:

$$\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3} \right)^3 < f \left(\frac{1}{3} \right) < \frac{112}{81} \left(\frac{1}{3} \right)^{3}$$

Comment: I don't get you. What is it that you want to say?

Comment: 1/3 (1/3)^3 < f (1/3) < 112/81(1/3)^3 = 1/81 < f (1/3) <112/2187                                                                                                  
     .Then do (112/2187 - 1/81) = 85/2187

Comment: Yes, that's correct.